# Periodically deletion of archived Wal files in postgres 12

Tags: windows, postgresql

I am working on postgres 12 with windows 10. It is a standalone system. I am using archiveWal for creating a postgres backup & point in time recovery. My archived Wal files are getting huge after few days. I want to delete archived Wal files periodically(For e.g. every hour).
I tried using pg_archivecleanup with command :-

```
pg_archivecleanup.exe C:\PostgreSQL\archiveWal 00000001000000000000003B
```

For pg_archivecleanup we have to provide the archived Wal file name in postges.conf so that it can delete files created before this file & postgres restart is required after the update.

Is there any other way or command to do periodically deletion of archived Wal files ?

Comment: How often do you take a full backup using `pg_basebackup`?

Comment: In our application we take scheduled back every night & user can take a backup at any time.

Comment: `pg_basebackup` will write a history file which you can use to detect which WAL archives can be cleaned out

Comment: From our application I can delete. I wanted to know if postgres provide any command to delete periodically.

Comment: This totally depends on the way you take your full backups. In case of `pg_basebackup` you can use the `backup_label` to determine the oldest WAL segment that can be removed

Comment: Is "archiveWal" the name of a specific product?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting WAL archives every few hours defies the purpose. You need to keep them as long as the oldest base backup you want to restore.

I would get more storage and create a job that deletes WAL archive files older than your backup retention time.

Comment: suppose `pg_dump` is used to backup regularly. How do I know which archived WAL can be deleted safely? Is it purely based on the backup retention time OR I just can delete every time after I run `checkpoint` followed by `pg_dump` ? thanks

Comment: If you use `pg_dump` for backups, you don't need to archive WAL at all, and the problem will go away.

Comment: yes, noted. But regardless pg_dump is being used, is the procedure (issuing `CHECKPOINT` then followed by `PG_DUMP`) correct? I just want to maximize the backup by issuing CHECKPOINT first.

Comment: Logical backups don't depend on a recent checkpoint for integrity. You are mixing things up.

Comment: ok, thanks. I was thinking that I can go as far as by using `checkpoint` so I can backup to the latest data possible.

Comment: `pg_dump` doesn't read the data that are persisted on disk, but the data that reside in the cache.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. I will not use `Checkpoint` then to backup database. Thanks